# Does assigning zero to a pointer destroy the allocated memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

My question may seem trivial for some people, but I don't understand why this code:

```
double * a = new double [3];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;

a = 0;

for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
cout << " a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << endl;

delete [] a ;
```

does not give the following result:

```
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = 0;
a[2] = 0;
```

Comment: Why do you think it would give this result?

Comment: You're indexing a null pointer. If you want to assign 0 to every element, use `std::fill(_n)`.

Comment: You are just changing the thing the pointer points to. First, it points to an array, next it points to nowhere. And nothing points to the array anymore.

Comment: @Borgleader well I thought that if I pointed to 0, then I would obviously 'cancel' any value in the allocated space... but now I see why it does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original memory allocated with `new[]` is leaked. You now have the equivalent of

```
double * a = 0; //or NULL
```

with memory leaks. Accessing the null pointer will give you undefined behavior. And no, assigning `0` to a pointer doesn't destroy the memory.

Comment: I think I understand that I cannot access anything after the NULL pointer, **even if the memory that I allocated before has not been destroyed**. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code will crash and/or produce some random result (if you assign some other constant to `a`).
Why?

In your code, `a` is a pointer to some region of the memory, which you are claiming for your own use (using `new`). So you have a value of `a` like `0x05237484` (just a random example). So, you know that by that address `0x05237484` there are 24 bytes (3*8, 8 is the size of a double) bytes reserved for you.
Essentially, when you say `new double[5]`, what you are saying to the runtime is:
"now, find me a space enough to store an array of 5 doubles, and reserve it for me, so only I can use it". The runtime reserves memory for you and stores the address in the pointer you've provided - `a`

Then, what you do is overwriting the pointer `a` with some other value. This means that the memory is still reserved for you (because you didn't tell the runtime you no longer need it, by using `delete` or `delete[]`), but you have forgotten about where it is stored.

Instead, your records now point to some other memory location - where there can be anything. So, either you will get some random values from where you are now pointing (if you happen to end up within same process memory), either your program will crash saying "Access violation" - meaning you've tried to access the memory belonging to another process/system/whatever.
What you're doing here after assigning `a = 0` is accessing 3 locations:

```
a[0] // which is a+0 == 0x00000000
a[1] // which is a+1 == 0x00000001
a[2] // which is a+2 == 0x00000002
```

You won't know what's at that location - but trying it, you'll either hit "access denied" error, or receive some random data (belonging to the other parts of application).

And, to make things worse, you've taken some memory to you but didn't release it - this means you've eaten up from your computer RAM for nothing. That's what called 'memory leak'

Comment: No, it shouldn't crash - it just leaks memory. `delete` with a NULL pointer is defined to be safe. Setting `a = 17;` would cause undefined behaviour (potential crash).

Comment: delete with a NULL pointer - yes, but what about reading? "Access violation - reading from address 0x000000" was a pretty frequent error back in Win98 days :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning zero to a pointer doesn't destroy the allocated memory, that pointer stopes to point to that memory segment. And after assigning  zero, `delete[]` will not delete that part of memory.